# Service worker cannot run to get the result

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use Chrome Extension manifest V3,
My manifestV3 configuration is as follows

```json
...
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
},
...
"action": {
    "default_icon": {
         "16": "img/icon.png",
          "32": "img/icon.png",
           "48": "img/icon.png",
           "64": "img/icon.png",
           "128": "img/icon.png"
     }
 },
...
```

My `background.js` is as follows:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
    console.log(tab);
    if (tab.url.startsWith('https://www.google.com')) {
        console.log('this is googlepage');
    } else {
        console.log('this is not googlepage');
    }
});
```

This is very easy, but I can't get the result of `console.log`.
Appeal everybody!

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you have to add "activeTab" or "tabs" permission in manifest to get url property.

Comment: My configuration about permissions is as follows:     "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "scripting",
        "cookies"
    ],                It contains  activeTab and tabs.

Comment: Open Devtools --> Console  and check if there are some errors.
Do it within 30 secs 'cause you could loose the log messages. (the SW go in idle mode after about 30")

Comment: Still no response...so strange issue

Comment: I guess you have just tried to reinstall the extension and\or restart the browser.

Comment: Could I send you my entire code, you can run it locally and see if run successfully. But it will take you time... How about this way

Comment: Fortunately, I solved the problem. I open page "chrome://inspect/#service-workers", click the "inspect" button of the service worker. It pop up a new DevTools. Its javascript context is `background.js` (service worker). The DevTools can show console log. Thank you very much. I've enjoyed talking with you.